# Scafflod revert

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have run `ruby script/generate scaffold  test name:string.....`

I want to reverse it.
Please give your opinion

Answer (score 7):

```
ruby script/destroy scaffold test
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by reversing (do you want to remove all the files that were created ??)

But if you want to revert the migration you can do so

rake db:rollback or rake db:rollback STEP=

cheers

sameera